# How to stream from ffmpeg to multiple udp clients?

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, streaming

Hello I'm streaming my own virtual camera to a localhost using ffmpeg using :

```
ffmpeg -re -f dshow -i video="VTX_VirtualCam":audio="VTX_VirtualMic" -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b 100000k -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:22588 -fflags nobuffer
```

It works fine but I only can connect to it from single client at the same time but I want to connect from different and multiple clients.

If I be connected and use another client it throws :

> bind failed: Error number -10048 occurred

How can I do this?
I have c++/c# programming skills as well if needed.